# how to properly use node modules with meteorhacks npm

Tags: node.js, meteor

First time trying to use node module with meteor

installed:

```
meteor add meteorhacks:npm
```

then installed:

```
npm install multer
```

have a separate file in the server directory, called "loadMulter" with just this one line:

```
var multer = Meteor.npmRequire('multer');
```

now, running "meteor" and getting this error:

```
W20150609-12:22:56.528(-5)? (STDERR)          
W20150609-12:22:56.528(-5)? (STDERR) /home/eugene/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20150609-12:22:56.529(-5)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20150609-12:22:56.529(-5)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20150609-12:22:56.531(-5)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: require is not defined
W20150609-12:22:56.531(-5)? (STDERR)     at app/node_modules/multer/node_modules/busboy/node_modules/dicer/node_modules/streamsearch/lib/sbmh.js:5:20
W20150609-12:22:56.531(-5)? (STDERR)     at app/node_modules/multer/node_modules/busboy/node_modules/dicer/node_modules/streamsearch/lib/sbmh.js:215:3
W20150609-12:22:56.531(-5)? (STDERR)     at /home/eugene/dev/meteor/socially/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150609-12:22:56.531(-5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150609-12:22:56.532(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/eugene/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150609-12:22:56.532(-5)? (STDERR)     at /home/eugene/dev/meteor/socially/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
```

What is the proper way to put these things together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't install the `npm` package as a local `node_module` using `npm install`.

You need to specify the packages you want in a special file named `package.json` created after you add `meteorhacks:npm` and launch Meteor.

```
{
  "multer": "0.1.8"
}
```

https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm#defining-packages

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run `npm install multer` in Meteor app.

The correct way is:

1. `meteor add meteorhacks:npm`
2. Create file `packages.json` in top level directory with content:

   ```
   {
     "multer": "0.1.8"
   }
   ```
3. Run `meteor`, the NPM package(s) will be installed automatically
4. Include npm package using [`Meteor.npmRequire`](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm#meteornpmrequirenpmmodulename)

Note: Be sure to delete node_modules folder created by previous `npm install`.